# Android: Changing TextView Position (Left or Right) Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, position, gravity

My XML Layout's TextView's are positioned to be by default at the left hand side of the View.

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="John Doe"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

How can I change the TextView position to be at the right hand side of the screen? I tried to do this using 'Gravity' but it doesn't change the position.

This is done from a GridView Adapter but I'm sure that doesn't affect anything. 
My code:

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comment_FB>{
    ArrayList<Comment_FB> comments; 
    Context ctx; 
    int resource; 
    String Fname;
    String Lname;


    public CommentsAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Comment_FB> commentsList, String Fname, String Lname) {
        super(context, resource, commentsList);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.comments = commentsList;
        this.ctx = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.Fname = Fname;
        this.Lname = Lname;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(comments.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return comments.size();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View child = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater(); // inflating your xml layout

        if (child == null) {            
            child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_single, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.user = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            holder.comment = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.user_comment);
            holder.date = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.image = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            child.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (RecordHolder) child.getTag();
        }

        final Comment_FB feedObj = comments.get(position); // you can remove the final modifieer.


        holder.comment.setText(feedObj.getComment());
        holder.user.setText(feedObj.getCommenter());
        holder.date.setText(feedObj.getDate());

        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("JezzaPref", 0);
        String curUser = pref.getString("current_user", null);
        if(feedObj.getCommenter().equals(curUser))
        {
            holder.comment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
            holder.comment.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.user.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.date.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }

        return child;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        public TextView date;
        public TextView user;
        public TextView comment;
        public ImageView image;
    }



    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() { // you can remove this..
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        if(getCount() == 0){
            //show layout or something that notifies that no list is in..
        }else{
            // this is to make sure that you can call notifyDataSetChanged in any place and any thread
            new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CommentsAdapter.super.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: please show us more code from you activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your views have `"wrap_content"` width you cannot move the text inside left or right. You should make them wider than your text to `setGravity()` could change anything.

Also, you have to know difference between `gravity` and `layout_gravity`. The first one is affecting to the text inside your Textview and the second one is affecting to the Textview relatively the views's layout.

The `setGravity()` method is affecting to the `gravity` parameter, not `layout_gravity`.

[image: For example:]

Answer (score 1):

[Specifies how to align the text by the view's x- and/or y-axis when the text is smaller than the view.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

*check the parent size *